For ODE $r^{-(N-1)}\left(r^{N-1} u^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}+\lambda e^u=0$, do we have $u^{\prime}(0)=0$?
For ODE $$r^{-(N-1)}\left(r^{N-1} u^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}+\lambda e^u=0$$ do we have $$u^{\prime}(0)=0?$$
Actually this is the radial case for
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rlr}
-\Delta u & =\lambda e^u \quad \text { in } B, \\
u & =0 \quad \text { on } \partial B,
\end{array}\right.
$$
My attempt:
Set $v(r)=r^{N-1} u^{\prime}(r)$, then
$$
\frac{d}{d r} v(r)+\lambda r^{N-1} e^u=0.
$$
Integrate from $0$ to $r$ we have
$$
v(r)-v(0)+\lambda \int_0^r s^{N-1} e^{u(s)} d s=0,
$$
then
$$
u^{\prime}(r)=r^{-(N-1)} v(r)=r^{-(N-1)}\left(v(0)-\lambda \int_0^r s^{N-1} e^{u(s)} d s\right).
$$
Since $u$ is smooth solution, then
$$
u(r)=u(0)+u^{\prime}(0) r+\frac{u^{\prime \prime}(0)}{2} r^2+\cdots
$$
then
$$
\int_0^r s^{N-1} e^{u(s)} d s \approx \int_0^r s^{N-1} e^{u(0)} d s=e^{u(0)} \int_0^r s^{N-1} d s=e^{u(0)} \frac{r^N}{N} .
$$
so when $r$ is small enough we have
$$
\int_0^r s^{N-1} e^{u(s)} d s \approx \frac{e^{u(0)}}{N} r^N .
$$
Then
$$
u^{\prime}(r)=r^{-(N-1)}\left(v(0)-\lambda \frac{e^{u(0)}}{N} r^N\right)=r^{-(N-1)} v(0)-\lambda \frac{e^{u(0)}}{N} r .
$$
To avoid the blow up of $u^{\prime}(0)$, we must have
$$v(0)=0,$$
so $u^{\prime}(0)=0 .$
Did I make mistake at any step?
